# Бэкап кластера базы данных

Tags: резервное-копирование, postgresql, debian

На Debian сервере работает PostgresQL. Дамп кластера делается штатными средствами:

```
pg_dumpall > database.outgzip database.out
```

Сейчас архив составляет порядка 100 Мб и хранится на сервере. Но, учитывая скорость роста кластера, скоро это будет нереально. Поэтому планируется создание отдельного бэкап-сервера.

Вопрос в том, как правильно организовать передачу и хранение архивов на бэкап-сервер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для организации полноценного сетевого хранилища данных подойдет [openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com/products):

> Openfiler converts an industry standard x86/64 architecture system into a full-fledged NAS/SAN appliance or IP storage gateway and provides storage administrators with a powerful tool to cope with burgeoning storage needs.

Пример настройки на русском: [создание домашнего сетевого хранилища (NAS) на базе Openfiler](http://www.nixp.ru/articles/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0-(NAS)-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-Openfiler.html).